# ionic 3 firebase compatibility issues

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to install firebase to my ionic 3 project with the command `npm install firebase @angular/fire` but after I install it, I am getting a lot of errors. I think there is a problem with my version of ionic(3) because I am getting no errors in that file if I uninstall the firebase.[image]

Is there a similar command for `npm install firebase @angular/fire` for ionic3?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.12.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (7 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.2
   native-run  : 1.2.2

System:

   NodeJS : v12.19.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.8
   OS     : Windows 10
```

```
+-- @ionic/app-scripts@3.2.4
| `-- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.0.35
|   `-- typescript@2.6.2
`-- typescript@2.3.4
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `ionic info` and the typescript version of your project into the question ?

Answer (score 2):

you can Install it using cordova :

**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x**
for using Capacitor :

**npm install cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x**

hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

For `Ionic`, you should use `Firebase X` plugin.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x

There is a section for `Ionic 3` : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#ionic-3

`Ionic Firebase X` is the maintained fork of the `Ionic Firebase` plugin, be careful to use `FirebaseX` and not `Firebase`.

Install it this way for Cordova :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
```

and this way for Capacitor :

```
npm install cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
```